# Multiple schemas when using Yup and React form hook?

Tags: reactjs, yup

I have a component with 2 forms. 1 for sign in, and 1 for sign up.

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email(),
  password: yup.string().min(4).max(20).required(),
});

export const LoginForm = ({onRequestClose} : Props) => {
  const {control, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm<IFormInputs>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
```

I have a Yup schema which I use in the react form hook resolver. This works for my login form because that only has a `email` and `password`

But on the sign up form I also have `userName` and `repeatPassword`. The issue is that if I add those properties to the schema the login doesn't work anymore. I think because it tries to validate fields the form doesn't supply but I'm not sure.

How do you add multiple schema's for forms in Yup?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved it by doing this:

```
  const {control: controlLogin, handleSubmit: handleSubmitLogin, formState: {errors: errorsLogin}} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(loginSchema),
  });

  const {control: controlSignUp, handleSubmit: handleSubmitSignUp, formState: {errors: errorsSignUp}} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schemaSignUp),
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's working, I'm used in my project like:

```
    //Yup schema for validation
    const editvalidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
          remark: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    });
    const {handleSubmit: handleSubmitEditRemark, register: reg, formState: {errors: errorsEditRemark}, setValue, clearErrors} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(editvalidationSchema),
    });

    // use
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmitEditRemark(editRemark)}>
       <input name="remark" type="text" className={`form-control ${errorsEditRemark.remark ? "is-invalid" : ""}`} defaultValue={data.remark)} autoFocus {...reg("remark")} />
       //submit button
       <Button type="submit"> Submit </Button>
    </Form>
```